# how to validate tinymce through jquery in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have many ascx control files in which I am using the tinymce editor and I am calling all ascx file in one master page on different different btn click.

Now I want, when I click on button A, and I have typed something into the tinymce editor and suddenly I click on button B then the page which is opened on btn click A must ask whether you need to save this text or not on btn click B.

How can I do it with the help of jquery? If there is some other way then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like you to refer to my answer here....

[Using the jQuery Validate plugin with the TinyMCE editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814439/using-the-jquery-validate-plugin-with-the-tinymce-editor)

It will solve your issue of validating the editor client side before sending it to server.

Answer (score 0):

When the user starts editing the content in tinymce editor set a flag `isContentChanged` to `true`. Add an event handler to the Button B. In the event handler, you can check for the `isContentChanged` flag and show an alert that the user is losing unsaved information, if the flag is true. You can use basic JS or Jquery to do this.

Comment: can i get that jquery for validating it[

Comment: actually in some page i have one textbox and in some i have many text tinymce editor so how could i validate that in different different btn click

Comment: is no one there to help me its urgent and i am not getting any idea to do it help me soon