# Using the jQuery Validate plugin with the TinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-validate, tinymce

I am implementing client validation using the Validate plugin for jQuery, and coming short with a form field that uses the TinyMCE editor component. This renders an incredibly complex control tree under the containing tag for my form field, including an `iframe` for the actual editing area, and a `textarea` element. I cannot access the `textarea` directly, so I add the 'required' attribute before calling `.validate()`, like below:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#wpsm_body").addClass("required");
    jQuery("#wpsm-send-mail")
            .validate(
                    {
                        errorContainer : "#wpsm-top-error-container, #wpsm-bottom-error-container",
                        errorLabelContainer : "#wpsm-top-error-container ul",
                        wrapper : "li",
                        messages : {
                            wpsm_from : "The message has no 'From' address. The administrator can set a default for this on the SuperMail 'Settings' page.",
                            wpsm_subject : "The message has no subject.",
                            wpsm_body : "The message has no body.",
                            wpsm_text : "The message has no body."
                        }
                    });
});
```

However, I get no client validation error when I submit the form even with an empty `wpsm_body`.

For background, this is inside a WordPress plugin, and TinyMCE is rendered by the `wp_editor` function, although I doubt this makes too much difference.

**Added:** While I don't believe this will help much at all, here is the HTML rendered to the browser. The HTML generated by TinyMCE subsequent to this is 400 lines long, and not relevant.

```
<form id="wpsm-send-mail" action="theform.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="wp-wpsm_body-wrap" class="wp-editor-wrap tmce-active">
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='editor-buttons-css' href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/css/editor-buttons.dev.css?ver=20111114'
        type='text/css' media='all' />
    <div id="wp-wpsm_body-editor-tools" class="wp-editor-tools">
        <a id="wpsm_body-html" class="hide-if-no-js wp-switch-editor switch-html" onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);">
            HTML</a> <a id="wpsm_body-tmce" class="hide-if-no-js wp-switch-editor switch-tmce"
                onclick="switchEditors.switchto(this);">Visual</a>
        <div id="wp-wpsm_body-media-buttons" class="hide-if-no-js wp-media-buttons">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=0&#038;TB_iframe=1"
                class="thickbox add_media" id="wpsm_body-add_media" title="Add Media" onclick="return false;">
                Upload/Insert
                <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/images/media-button.png?ver=20111005"
                    width="15" height="15" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wp-wpsm_body-editor-container" class="wp-editor-container">
        <textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="20" cols="40" name="wpsm_body" id="wpsm_body"></textarea></div>
</div>
</form>
```

The only relevant items here are the `form` and `textarea`, and their `id` attributes.

Comment: @ori, see my edit. I have added what HTML is is feasible to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming You have already included the js file for tinyMCE and you are doing the validation on client side using `tinyMCE`

Following is the code to validate the tinyMCE editor

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {  

        var $btn = $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>");  
        var $txtEditor = $(".txtEditor");  

        $btn.click(function () {  
            if (tinyMCE.get($txtEditor.attr("id")).getContent() == "") {  
                alert("hi");  
            }  
            else {  
                alert("bye");  
            }  
            return false;  
        })  

    });  

</script>  


<div>  
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="txtEditor212"></asp:TextBox>  
            <asp:TextBox id="txtEditor" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="txtEditor"></asp:TextBox>  
        </div>  
        <div>  
        <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />  

        </div>  
</asp:Content>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how TinyMCE is used in Wordpress.

But I've used TinyMCE before, and the `textarea` doesn't get updated as you make edits in the rich text editor (it does get updated on form submit). I used the following code to update the textarea when I needed to (ajax):

```
form.find('textarea.rich').each(function() {
    var textarea = $(this);
    var taeditor = tinyMCE.get(textarea.attr('id'));
    if (taeditor) 
        textarea.val(taeditor.getContent());
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not that the textarea is not getting updated. It is that even without it getting updated, i.e. remaining blank, I get no validation error.

Comment: You're right, my answer might have helped the next problem... other than that your code looks like it should work, so some good old debugging's in order: does the textarea stay empty when wp creates the editor, does wp duplicate the textarea's id? etc.